# Which resistor can be replaced by a potentiometer to adjust the current on this power supply which uses a FAN4803 chip?

Tags: power-supply, constant-current

The power supply schematic:

[image: Schematic for FAN4803]

Here is the FAN4803 IC datasheet:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/FAN4803-1-1191942.pdf

**ISENSE**

- This pin ties to a resistor or current sense transformer which
  senses the PFC input current. This signal should be negative
  with respect to the IC ground. It internally feeds the pulseby-
  pulse current limit comparator and the current sense feedback
  signal. The ILIMIT trip level is –1V. The ISENSE feedback
  is internally multiplied by a gain of four and compared
  against the internal programmed ramp to set the PFC duty
  cycle. The intersection of the boost inductor current
  downslope with the internal programming ramp determines
  the boost off-time.

**ILIMIT**

- This pin is tied to the primary side PWM current sense resistor
  or transformer. It provides the internal pulse-by-pulse
  current limit for the PWM stage (which occurs at 1.5V) and
  the peak current mode feedback path for the current mode
  control of the PWM stage. The current ramp is offset internally
  by 1.2V and then compared against the opto feedback
  voltage to set the PWM duty cycle.

It outputs 12v 20A and uses constant current mode for overload protection.  I want to  to be able to adjust the current from 1A-20A using a potentiometer.

I've tried lowering the resistance of the R4 resistor from 1k to 5 ohms as well as R11 resistor from 150 to 5 ohms, but the output current remains the same.

Do I need to change the value of the R3 or R10 shunt to a different fixed value instead of using a  potentiometer?

Comment: In this 2-SW forward configuration, there is no secondary-side current sensing so you can a) add a constant-current regulation loop or b) try to limit the current in the primary side. To limit the current in the primary side, you will have to provide a variable dc offset to the \$I_{limit}\$ pin. There seems to be a 1.5-V upper limit so the more dc you offset the pin with, the closer you'll get to 1.5 V and the lower the 2-SW peak current current. This won't be very precise but it can work. When you hit the limit, the IC will go into hiccup mode. Let me know if you want me to document this.

Answer (score 0):

Output voltage is regulated by means of R15 and R16. Try replacing R15 with a 10k potentiometer, perhaps with a 1k series resistor to guard against zero ohms setting at extreme.

Sorry, I misread your question, and see you want to regulate current. I'm not sure it's designed to operate as a current regulator instead of current limiter. It will probably require changing a shunt value, or using a voltage divider on the shunt. Probably R4 and R28.